# Vertically Merge two tables based on a similar column with duplicate values

Tags: python, sql, join, merge

I want to vertically merge two tables by one similar column with multiple duplicates values. I tried using join but it merged with many to many values but in my case I need simple merge to prepare a file.

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Try to put some of your code which you tried. So we can easily understand where you exactly struct..

Comment: Also, which RDBMS are you using? And do you expect to do the job in SQL or in Python (since you tagged both)?

Comment: Query is like this
SELECT a.x, a.y, b.z FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.x =b.x

I am using Oracle SQL, I tagged Python if there is any way to perform this operation in PYthon also

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

This looks like a `full join`.  In standard SQL:

```
select coalesce(t1.x, t2.x) as x, t1.y, t2.z
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.x = t2.x and t1.y = t2.z;
```

Comment: Coincidently all values of y and z are similar but that's not the case, updating the table.

Comment: @SamarthKhandelwal . . . Rather than invalidating an answer, it is better to ask a new question, with sample data and desired results **as text tables** and an appropriate database tag and a clear explanation of what you want.

Comment: sorry for that but I am invalidating the answer, I just updated it, I  will post another one. Moreover, if you see in question description I have to merge them on one column (based on a similar column) but in your answer you have used y and z also to merge them. Thanks anyways